# How to handle server side Authentication in nextjs?

Tags: axios, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm setting Token in localstorage and send it to every request with (**axios**), but the problem is when I use getServerSideProps token is not send because localStorage can't be accessed on server side.

I think I should use Cookies, I tried **js-cookies** but it didn't work on server as well.

Is there any solution to send token on server side fetching function as **getServerSideProps** and **getStaticProps**?

Comment: Which lib are you using for authentication?

Comment: Actually, I don't use any I just store token at redux-store and localstorage, and send it with every client side request.

Comment: You can't access `localStorage` from `getServerSideProps` as it runs on the server. Try using cookies to store the token instead, OR move the authentication to the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage is client-side only; use `getInitialProps`

```js
function Page({ stars }) {
    return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div>
}
        
Page.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
    let token;
    
    // server
    if (req) return { page: {} };
    else {
        // client
        const token = localStorage.getItem("auth");
        const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js', { headers: { Authorization: token }});
        const data = await res.json();
        return { page: data };
    }
};

export default Page
```

Just modify my code, normally it works

Comment: This doesn't fully solve the issue. The auth logic won't run when the page is first loaded and `getInitialProps` runs on the server.

Comment: I'm currently making the requests that needs auth on client side, but I think this is not the best approach, and I'm not making good use of ssr with nextjs.